# Making a simple javascript Image gallery

Tags: javascript, image-gallery

I'm trying to make a very simple Image gallery. Most of the design is already complete (used JQuery)...but now I'm trying to think out the logic it takes to get the images to change. For this part I was thinking I would just use javaScript instead of Jquery just to keep it simple. I'm not too familiar with the javaScript syntax but this is my attempt to get started. Is this a feasible way to create an image gallery? I know making the images the background isn't a great idea, but for testing purposes I don't feel like cropping images -- so setting the image as the background trims the images to fit.

I was also trying to think about how to set the ImageCnt to zero initially... Can an onload function be used to set the ImageCnt to 0 when the page loads? Can a var be passed into next()? If so, I could pass the current ImageCnt from the onClick to the function.

PS. I've omitted a lot of code to keep it simple to read, but I can provide more if it's necessary.

Thanks! here's my code:

## Javascript

```
<script>
  function next()
  {
    var myImage= new Array(); 
    myImage[0]="penguins.jpg";       
    myImage[1]="desert.jpg";
    myImage[2]="jellyfish.jpg";
    myImage[3]="flower.jpg"; 

    ImageCnt++;

    document.getElementById("whiteBox").style.background = 'url(myImage[ImageCnt])';
  }
</script>
```

## html

```
<a href="#" onclick="next()"><img src="next.png"/></a>
```

Comment: This should work fine, are you having any problems? However, I would suggest declaring the image array as a global so that it doesn't have to be recreated every time the function is called.

Comment: Rather than reinventing the wheel, there are jQuery plugins which have already done the work for you.

Comment: I personally prefer javascript to jQuery on simple things like this because of jQuery's execution times.

Comment: I don't think the document.getElementById("whiteBox").style.background = 'url(myImage[ImageCnt])' is working....It worked when I just put the image url in as the parameter, but it doesn't work with the array.

Comment: What is the path to the images on the server? For example, are they in an "images" folder or are they just in the root directory with the page itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most importantly, you need to build the background property by concatenating ("+" operator) its different parts, as shown below ; otherwise it won't be replaced by the values from your array if you make it a static string.

Also use the global scope to declare and initialize your image array and counter :

```
<script>
var myImage= new Array(); 
myImage[0]="penguins.jpg";       
myImage[1]="desert.jpg";
myImage[2]="jellyfish.jpg";
myImage[3]="flower.jpg"; 

var ImageCnt = 0;

function next(){
    ImageCnt++;
    document.getElementById("whiteBox").style.background = 'url(' + myImage[ImageCnt] + ')';
  }
</script>
```

Finally, return false from onclick otherwise you'll reload the page :

```
<a href="#" onclick="next();return false;"><img src="next.png"/></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was having a hard time getting the syntax right. I would not have guessed the I needed to concatenate like that. It works perfectly now :D

Answer (score 3):

This is the best example of a simple inline non-jQuery image gallery that I've found, obtained from [http://extremestudio.ro/](http://extremestudio.ro/create-a-html-photo-gallery-valid-for-all-browsers/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Simple and Effective Photo Gallery with HTML and JavaScript
    </title>

    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        background: #222;
        margin-top: 20px;
      }

      h3 {
        color: #eee;
        font-family: Verdana;
      }

      .thumbnails img {
        height: 80px;
        border: 4px solid #555;
        padding: 1px;
        margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
      }

      .thumbnails img:hover {
        border: 4px solid #00ccff;
        cursor:pointer;
      }

      .preview img {
        border: 4px solid #444;
        padding: 1px;
        width: 400px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="gallery" align="center">
      <h3>Simple and Effective Photo Gallery with HTML and JavaScript</h3><br/>

      <div class="thumbnails">
        <img onmouseover="preview.src=img1.src" id="img1" src="http://bit.ly/2rz3hy" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
        <img onmouseover="preview.src=img2.src" id="img2" src="http://bit.ly/1ug1e6" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
        <img onmouseover="preview.src=img3.src" id="img3" src="http://bit.ly/1yIAYc" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
        <img onmouseover="preview.src=img4.src" id="img4" src="http://bit.ly/2LHyDW" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
        <img onmouseover="preview.src=img5.src" id="img5" src="http://bit.ly/2wyHSR" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
        <img onmouseover="preview.src=img6.src" id="img6" src="http://bit.ly/yRo1i" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
      </div><br/>

      <div class="preview" align="center">
        <img id="preview" src="http://bit.ly/2rz3hy" alt="No Image Loaded"/>
      </div><br/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The only javascript is embedded in the  tags, but could easily be moved to script tags for more flexibility.