# Pure javascript image gallery with fwd and bck function

Tags: javascript, html, image-gallery

Hi I know it is a partly duplicate question but i had no other option as other questions cover it only partly [Making a simple javascript Image gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299917/making-a-simple-javascript-image-gallery). Actually I made this js image gallery code but it not working. Can anyone please help explain what's going on.

### JAVASCRIPT

```
var imageGallery = new Array();
imageGallery[0] = '2.png';
imageGallery[1] = '3.png';
imageGallery[2] = '4.png';
imageGallery[3] = '5.png';
imageGallery[4] = '6.png';
var imgCount = 0;
function next() {
    imgCount++ ;
    document.getElementById("gallery").style.background = 'url(' + imageGallery[imgCount] + ')';
}

function previous() {
    imgCount--;
    document.getElementById("gallery").style.background = 'url(' + imageGallery[imgCount] + ')';    
    }
```

### HTML

```
<a href onclick="next(); return = false;">Next</a>
<a href onclick="previous(); return = false;">Back</a>
<div id="gallery" style="background: url(1.png); height:420px; width:744px"></div>
```

TBN: This is not the final code as next and previous buttons keep on executing as long as they are pressed.

Comment: Well, what **is** going on?  If you don't describe the problem, it's hard to help.

Comment: simply it's not working...I mean buttons don't work.

Comment: `simply it's not working` doesn't tell what you are trying to do, do you want to change images on click only ?

Comment: change your <a> tags to.... <a href="" onclick="next(); return false;">Next</a>
<a href="" onclick="previous(); return false;">Back</a>  .. and see if it works..

Comment: @Recovering Yeah I just want to make this image gallery using just javascript.

Comment: @Psych Nope....it doesn't.

Comment: @BlackHawk check my answer.. and the link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay.. so here's very simple gallery... that does only what your question's code does.. actually i only corrected it.. so click next and back... and get new images.. i did it very quickly.. so many things are missing for it to be called a gallery.. any ways [you can fiddle with it here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ys2NT/)

changed your markup to..

```
<a href="#" onclick="next(); return false;">Next</a>
<a href="#" onclick="previous(); return false;">Back</a>
<img id="gallery" src="http://i26.tinypic.com/2hwx3c.jpg" style="height:420px; width:744px" >
```

and your script to...

```
var imageGallery = [
 "http://i26.tinypic.com/2hwx3c.jpg" ,      
 "http://i43.tinypic.com/2iqxpg1.jpg" ,
  "http://i40.tinypic.com/2agls15.jpg" ,
  "http://i41.tinypic.com/2ym9f01.jpg",
  "http://i32.tinypic.com/14aa4o7.jpg"
  ];

var imgCount = 0;
var totalImgs = imageGallery.length - 1;

function next() {
    imgCount++ ;
   if(imgCount > totalImgs) imgCount = 0

   document.getElementById("gallery").src = imageGallery[imgCount] ;
}

function previous() {
    imgCount--;
  if(imgCount < 0) imgCount = totalImgs ;
       document.getElementById("gallery").src = imageGallery[imgCount] ;    
    }
```

Comment: but can I know why my code isn't working on the contrary if you remove the back functionality and all the related code it works fine...???

Comment: @BlackHawk okay.. so let's examine your code.. umm... where do i start.. i already pointed out the return = false.. is not valid in javascript..

Comment: I too thought that because it didn't work but that is what was written in the answer referred in the question. But it isn't working without it as well.

Comment: @BlackHawk yeah your code is working also.. hmm..  anyways.. just tell me if you want my help in creating this image gallery.. i will be glad to help you,... :D

Answer (score 1):

have you considered a different approach to your gallery?

rather than doing an image count add a class to each img that's on top of active then each time the img switches update the classes

Comment: to be frank i have 35 images and giving every image a class that's kind of clumsy...

Comment: I don't think i explained myself correctly check out this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Nr8bz/

Comment: @swsa umm.. read the question title again.. hello?? Pure javascript means no library at all.. and yes.. jQuery is a library...