# How would I make my javascript image gallery return to the start after it has gone through all the images?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am making my own Wordpress plugin for my own website to see what I can do. I used the code here ([Making a simple javascript Image gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299917/making-a-simple-javascript-image-gallery)) for the basis of it and I want it to cycle through all the set images and then go back to start and loop all the images when the user presses the 'next' button. What would be the most efficient way of achieving this?

I am new to JS so I have no idea what to do. I have searched Google and didn't find how to do it

```
var myImage= new Array(); 
myImage[0]="/wp-content/plugins/gallery/imgs/img1.png";       
myImage[1]="/wp-content/plugins/gallery/imgs/img2.png";
myImage[2]="/wp-content/plugins/gallery/imgs/img3.png";

var ImageCnt = 0;

function next(){
    ImageCnt++;
    document.getElementById("whiteBox").src = myImage[ImageCnt];
  }
```

If you need the PHP file for the plugin as well (contains 'next' function) just ask and I will send it

Comment: Probably a good idea to go ahead and add the PHP code, too.

Comment: @DrSatan1 Thanks for your interest in helping me, but I had a successful answer that you can see on the page. Thanks anyway. If you want it to make your own plugin, just ask and I will post it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add

```
if(ImageCnt >= myImage.length){
  ImageCnt = 0;
}
```

or you can make it better by

```
ImageCnt %= myImage.length;
```

This 2 methods will work the same

If you don't understand the second method (`%`) please read this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-do-math-in-javascript-with-operators#modulo

```js
var myImage= new Array(); 
myImage[0]="https://placekitten.com/200/300";       
myImage[1]="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300";

var ImageCnt = 0;

function next(){
    ImageCnt++;
    
    ImageCnt %= myImage.length
    //if(ImageCnt >= myImage.length){
    //  ImageCnt = 0;
    //}
    document.getElementById("whiteBox").src = myImage[ImageCnt];
}
```

```css
#whiteBox{
width:100%;
height:300px;
}

.next{
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<img id="whiteBox" src="https://placekitten.com/200/300">
<div class="next" onclick="next()">next</div>
```

Comment: Wow! That worked great! Just added the 'ImageCnt %= myImage.length;' and worked great! Thanks

Comment: No problem. And welcome to Stackoverflow as a new member :)